# Present continuous verb with does

Tags: sentence-construction, gerunds, present-tense, present-continuous

Is this sentence correct?

**He does blogging.**

If so, what would be the meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is correct but it is not in present continuous. This is simple present. Blogging is gerund here (Verb+ing used as noun).